# How to change Woocommerce Admin Breadcrumb Link Title

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I've tried to add gettext in the function.php like this,

```
add_filter(  'gettext',  'wps_translate_words_array'  );
add_filter(  'ngettext',  'wps_translate_words_array'  );
function wps_translate_words_array( $translated ) {

     $words = array(
            // 'word to translate' = > 'translation'
            'WooCommerce' => 'Home',
     );

     $translated = str_ireplace(array_keys($words), $words, $translated );
     return $translated;
}
```

but it doesn't work!

[image]